# App rename with Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am working with titanium for mobile app development. I am using appcelerator for the development. I have created one project and now I am trying to change the display name of the app from ti.xml file. When I am running the app on android phone it is installing two apps on my phone with the same name. And none of the app is opening I am getting unfortunately stopped error when I am trying to open the app.

I am trying to change the name tag from ti.xml file

```
<name> NewAppName </name>
```

Help me out if you know any other way to change the display name of app.

Answer (score 0):

First delete all those apps from your device, and  tag is used to rename the app, just take care that it should not contain blank spaces in front